# Pegar os valores do textarea separado por linha

Tags: javascript

Como pegar o valor do `textarea` separados por linha e adicionar uma `div`?

Gostaria de escrever um texto no `textarea` separado por linhas e mandar para o outro textarea adicionando uma `div` com o atributo `class` com numeros crescentes em cada linha como nos exemplos abaixo:

**Meu código (que funciona apenas com 1 linha):**

```js
function text(){

   var txt = document.getElementById('txt')
   var ext = document.getElementById('ext')

   ext.value = "<div class='classe1'>" +txt.value+ "</div>"
}
```

```html
<textarea id="txt" oninput="text()"></textarea><br><textarea id="ext"></textarea>
```

**Exemplo de onde quero chegar:**

```html
<textarea style='height:60px;'>Texto 1
Texto 2
Texto 3</textarea><br>
<textarea id="txt" style='height:60px;'><div class="class1">Texto 1</div>
<div class="class2">Texto 2</div>
<div class="class3">Texto 3</div></textarea>
```

Comment: Explique melhor a sua dúvida, ficou um pouco confuso.

Comment: Não está relacionado à resposta, mas `<div>` não tem o atributo `name` (pelo menos em HTML válido). Para que você precisa do `name`? Você poderia usar `id` ou `class` se for só para manipulação de HTML ou `<input type="hidden">` se for para enviar os dados em inputs separados.

Comment: é só um exemplo eu simplesmente poderia mudar para `class`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quebrando o problema em partes pode-se resolver da seguinte maneira:

Supondo que um `textarea` contenha o texto:

```
abc
123

xyz
```

1. Quebrar seu texto em um array usando [`String.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split);

   ```
   let linhas = txt.value.split('\n')
   // ["abc", "123", "", "xyz"]
   ```
2. [Opcional] remover as linhas em branco para não gerar `<div>`s vazias usando [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter);

   ```
   let linhas_nao_vazias = linhas.filter(linha => linha.trim())
   // ["abc", "123", "xyz"]
   ```
3. Adicionar o texto de cada linha dentro das `<div>` usando [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) e [`Template strings`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

   ```
   let divs = linhas_nao_vazias.map((linha, i) => `
       <div class="texto${i+1}">
           ${linha}
       </div>
   `)
   // [
   //     "<div class=\"texto1\">abc</div>", 
   //     "<div class=\"texto2\">123</div>", 
   //     "<div class=\"texto3\">xyz</div>"
   // ]
   ```
4. Unir as `<div>`s em uma única string com [`Array.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

   ```
   // quebra de linha apenas para visual, poderia ser ''
   let resultado = divs.join('\n')
   // "<div class=\"texto1\">abc</div>
   // <div class=\"texto2\">123</div>
   // <div class=\"texto3\">xyz</div>"
   ```
5. Atribuir o resultado a outro `<textarea>`

   ```
   outro_txt.value = resultado
   ```

---

No fim fica simples:

```js
let txt = document.getElementById('texto')
let resultado = document.getElementById('resultado')

txt.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
    resultado.value = txt.value
        .split('\n')
        .filter(linha => linha.trim())
        .map((linha, i) => `<div class="linha${i+1}">${linha}</div>` )
        .join('\n')
})
```

```css
textarea { width: 100% }
```

```html
<textarea id="texto" rows=4></textarea>
<hr>
<textarea id="resultado" rows=4></textarea>
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer utilizando o `split()` para montar uma lista com as linhas e percorrê-la colocando as tags de `<div>` e acrescentando no ext:

```js
function text(){

   var txt = document.getElementById('txt')
   var ext = document.getElementById('ext')

   var list = txt.value.split("\n")

   ext.value = ""
   for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
       if (list[i].length > 0) {
           ext.value += "<div>"+list[i]+" "+i+"</div>"
       }
   }
}
```

```html
<textarea id="txt" oninput="text()"></textarea><br><textarea id="ext"></textarea>
```

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta.

Comment: se eu quiser adicionar um numero crescente junto com a `div`, por exemplo no atributo `class`: `<div class="class1">Texto</div>` depois `<div class="class2">Outro texto</div>` como faço?

Comment: @Mark alterando o foreach por um for convencional você consegue o numero correspondente a posição do item.

Answer (score 2):

Uma outra opção com `regex`.

```js
function texto(){
   /// a chamada `texto.call(this)` faz com que nexte momento this seja o textarea
 
   var value = this.value,
       dest = document.getElementById('etxt'); // textarea destino

   dest.value = ""; // <- limpa o valor anterior
   
   var i=0; // <- contador
   value.replace(/([^\n\r]+)/g, // <- regex qualquer valor que não seja nova linha
       function(x){ // <- funcão chamada para cada linha
           i++; // <- incrementa contador
           dest.value += "<div>"+x+" "+i+"</div>\n"; 
          //     ^                     ^
          //     |                     contador
          //     entra com o novo valor no textarea destino

       }
   );
}
```

```html
<textarea id='txt' oninput='texto.call(this)'></textarea><br/>
<textarea id='etxt'></textarea>
```

Comment: Eu atualizei a pergunta, resumindo: Se eu quiser adicionar um numero crescente junto com a div, por exemplo no atributo class: `<div class="class1">Texto</div>` depois `<div class="class2">Outro texto</div>` como faço?

Comment: Ou no proprio texto tipo: `<div>Texto 1</div>` `<div>Texto 2</div>`

Answer (score 0):

Você pode tentar da seguinte forma, além de fácil vai atender todos
os seus requisitos.

```js
const textArea = document.querySelector('#card-text');
textArea.addEventListener('input', function(event) {
      //quando uma linha é apagada auto-redimenciona
      textArea.style.height = 'auto';

      //se auto-redimenciona quando uma nova linha
      //é criada
      const sHeight = event.target.scrollHeight
      textArea.style.height = `${sHeight}px`;
})
```

```css
#card-text {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  resize: none;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  border-radius: 3px;
  outline: none;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 260px;
  min-height: 50px;
  color: gray;
}


/*esconde a scrollbar*/
#card-text::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">-->
</head>

<body>
  <textarea id="card-text" rows="1"></textarea>
</body>

</html>
```

```
insira o código aqui
```